# Combination and permutation combo

Tags: permutations, combinations

What would be the formula to calculate the total possible outcome for this scenario:

Given x amount of teams, each team has exactly n amount of players. What are the possible outcomes for groups of size r where you can only have one player of each team.

Example: 4 teams (A-D),   4 players each team, 4 players each grouping.

Possible groupings are:

A1, B1, C1, D1

A1, B3, C1, D2

But not

A1, A3, C2, D2

B3, C2, D4, B1

Comment: Please think about your question and make it more clear.  Presumably you  mean "one player of each team".  Is the group one from each team?  Could it be a different size?

Comment: Yes i messed up. And the grouping of x

Answer (score 1):

First choose the $r$ teams you will pick players from in $x \choose r$ ways.  Then for each team you have $n$ choices of the player.  Each choice is independent, so multiply them, giving a total of $${x \choose r}n^r$$

Comment: I have some updated information that I want to provide. Since each player has to be with a new unique opponent.

I'll be creating a new post